# Why is considering $\delta(\mu)$ as Fourier transform for $f(t) = 1$ rational?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, transformation

We know for a function $f(t)$, Fourier transform is defined as:

\begin{equation}
F(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i2\pi \mu t} dt
\end{equation}

I saw the Fourier transformation for $f(t) = 1$ is $\delta(\mu)$. It is usually achieved by *duality* property of Fourier transform. But I want to get it directly. So I attempted to

$$F(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i2\pi \mu t} dt \tag{1}$$

With attention to this relation:

$$\int e^{-i2\pi \mu t} dt = \frac{i e^{-i2\pi \mu t}}{2\pi\mu}  \tag{2}$$

It is obvious that $F(\mu)$ in Equation$(1)$ for $\mu = 0$ is $\infty$, which matches the $\delta(0)$. But Equation$(2)$ shows the result of Equation$(1)$ for $\mu \neq 0$ is *imaginary*, not converge and also $|F(\mu)| = \infty$.

Now my question is: When result of Equation$(1)$, which is definition of Fourier transform of $f(t) = 1$, is *so irrelevant* to $\delta(\mu)$, is it rational to consider $\delta(\mu)$ as Fourier transform for $f(t) = 1$?

Comment: Look at the Fourier transforms of $\mathbf{1}_{[-R,R]}$ or $e^{-x^2/R^2}$ as $R\to\infty.$ These functions have Fourier transforms and the functions tend to $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}$ as $R\to\infty.$ Their Fourier transforms are functions that tend to $\delta.$

Comment: @md2perpe I think Fourier transforms of $\mathbf{1}_{[-R,R]}$ is:
\begin{align}
\frac{i}{2\pi \mu}(e^{-i2\pi\mu R}-e^{i2\pi\mu R})
\end{align}
 and when $R\to\infty$ it will be 
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\frac{-i}{2\pi \mu}e^{i2\pi\mu R}
\end{align}
Now how is it tend to $\delta$?

Comment: Not that you have imaginary numbers in the exponents; no term will be dominant for big $R.$ The parenthesis can be simplified to $2i\sin(2\pi\mu R).$ You will also have $R,$ not $\mu,$ in the denominator. Then $(\sin R\mu)/R \to c \delta(\mu)$ for some constant $c.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“It is usually achieved by duality”, well that’s how one precisely defines and obtain this relationship. The integral definition makes no sense whatsoever as a Lebesgue integral sincce $t\mapsto e^{-2\pi i \mu t}$ is not in $L^1(\Bbb{R})$. Also, $\delta$ is not defined as “$\delta(\mu)=0$ for $\mu\neq 0$ and $\delta(0)=\infty$”, no matter how much one may hear/wish to believe otherwise. If it were defined pointwise like this, it would never be able to satisfy its defining property $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\delta(x)\phi(x)\,dx=\phi(0)$ for all test functions $\phi$.

Also, $|F(\mu)|=\infty$ for $\mu\neq 0$ makes no sense. Literally. The very symbol $F(\mu)$ makes no sense because you’re integrating a non $L^1$ function, so as far as any reason is concerned, this is just a string of meaningless symbols.

Now, precisely because the constant function $f=1$ does not belong to $L^1$ or to $L^2$, we cannot use the integral definitions. We have to resort to duality of the Schwartz functions and tempered distributions.

Comment: (+1) Aptly written.